# Website & Forum sharing the same login credentials?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, php

I am going to be running a small site (100 hits a week maybe) and I am looking for a quick and easy way to share login information between the main website, a control panel (webmin, cpanel, or something), and the forum.

One login needed to access any of the three. The website won't have use for the login, per say. But it will display "logged in" when you are on the website.

Any custom solutions, any thoughts, logic, examples?

Comment: do you have a forum or cpanel script in mind and how good at coding are you? This also would fit more on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

If you're comfortable with MySQL, you might take a look at using [mod_auth_mysql](http://modauthmysql.sourceforge.net/). It would be a simple way to manage a lot of users with simple (directory/file) permissions on the website/cpanel end.

On the forum end, you could tell mod_auth_mysql to use the forum's authentication database, assuming they support the same kind of password hashes - some basic hacking of the forum software could probably fix that if it wasn't the case.

Once you've got directory access control in Apache, you can use the "remote user" environment variable in Perl/PHP/Python/whatever to display the welcome message you want at the top of every page. For example, take this CGI script in Perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use CGI;
my $co = new CGI;
print $co->header("text/html");
print "Hello,".$ENV{'REMOTE_USER'}."!";
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify all the application's login files to all share the same database therefore all applications will use the same credentials.

Comment: wont share the same sessions though, you have to modify all the pages to accept the same session info

Answer (score 0):

If you are constructing the site from the ground up, you can use a CMS such as Drupal, which has a forum module that can be integrated into the site.